# why github actions can't find Dockerfile in a specific folder or even in a root folder?

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, github-actions

I am using ec2 ubuntu. Reactjs Nextjs App dockerized. Wanted to use github actions self hosted.

This is my `node.js.yaml`

```
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: self-hosted

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [18.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - name: Check out code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
    - name: Configure AWS credentials
      uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
      with:
        aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        aws-region: us-east-2

    - name: Login to Amazon ECR
      id: login-ecr
      uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v1

    - name: Build, tag, and push image to Amazon ECR
#       with:
#         context: ./devops/docker
#         file: ./devops/docker/Dockerfile.local
      env:
        ECR_REGISTRY: ${{ steps.login-ecr.outputs.registry }}
        ECR_REPOSITORY: docker_nodejs_demo
        IMAGE_TAG: nodejs_demo_image
      run: |
        docker build . -f devops/docker/dockerfile.local -t recipe-1
        docker tag recipe-1:latest ******.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/recipe-1:latest 
        docker push ******.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/recipe-1:latest
```

Folder structure in ec2 ubuntu:
My project folder: `/home/ubuntu/actions-runner/_work/recipe-1/recipe-1`
My Dockerfile: `/home/ubuntu/actions-runner/_work/recipe-1/recipe-1/devops/docker/Dockerfile.local`

The ISSUE:

Error: Unable to locate executable file: docker. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also check the file mode to verify the file is executable.
0s

[image]

Tried:

1. i tried using this command `docker build . -f devops/docker/dockerfile.local -t recipe-1`
2. i tried transferring the `Dockerfile.local` to root folder as `Dockerfile`, then using `docker build . -t recipe-1`
3. i tried using path `with` `file` path option, it can be seen commented in my node.js.yaml, then using this command `docker build . -t recipe-1`

None of this worked.

Comment: Your error doesn't say it can't find your Dockerfile. It says, `Unable to locate executable file docker`. It can't find the `docker` program; this has nothing to do with your Dockerfile. It appears that Docker isn't installed on the machine on which you're running this workflow.

Comment: @larsks oh i see, lets me check it again.